# Python "if" statement appears to allow namespaces to be defined even if the statement is bypassed

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script (delete.py) that calls an API to delete an object. And I have a script (remote.py) that calls the delObj() function in delete.py to delete an object. The function in delete.py (delObj()) doesn't need any arguments when it runs as **main**, but when it is called by remote.py it needs arguments. So (part of) the script looks like:

```
    def delObj(*args):
        if __name__ != "__main__":
            var0 = args[0]
            var1 = args[1]
    .
    .
    .

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        var0 = "name of item to delete"
        var1 = "ID of item to delete"
        delObj()
```

The code above works as expected when called by remote.py. But when I run delete.py -- which fails the "name doesn't equal main" statement, the script fails saying:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var0' referenced before assignment
```

If I change the if statement to:

```
def delObj(*args):
    if args != '':
        var0 = args[0]
        var1 = args[1]
```

I get an error message:

```
var0 = args[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

To fix either error I can place a "global var0, var1" statement above the "if" block.

So that sounds to me like the "var0, var0" names are actually created in function local namespace regardless of whether the "if" statement is true or false. So I have to declare a global variable in order to change the values for var0 and var1, either from NULL if no arguments are passed or to the values that are passed from the opening of the script.

Does that sound right?
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: If a function contains an assignment to a variable, that variable defaults to being local.  It doesn't matter if the assignment is inside a conditional statement.  Your code would be much clearer if `var0` and `var1` were parameters of the function, explicitly passed to the function when called in either manner.

Comment: I understand your comment, variables inside a function are local to the function. And yes, my code now is "clearer"  because I modified it to always pass params to the function. But my question is why the vars inside the condition have values that are used even if the condition is not met.

Comment: No, a variable inside a function is only local in the presence of an assignment to that variable.  A variable that isn't assigned within the function defaults to being global, as there's nothing else that such a variable could possibly be.

Comment: Thanks for responding jasonharper. I am still asking why variables in a condition that's not met even come into play.

Comment: Ok, one more try... The storage type (local vs. global) of a variable is determined within each function entirely at compile time - it cannot be different in different parts of a single function, it cannot depend on anything that happens at runtime.  Your function contains an assignment to these variables; the fact that the assignment is inside a condition that isn't true is *completely irrelevant*.  They are therefore local variables (in the absence of an explicit `global` declaration), and therefore cannot refer to the global variables of the same names that exist outside of the function.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your patience . . . it may have been exasperating to tell me the same thing over and over. But I finally get it that the assignment inside a condition is irrelevant. And I am not sure how to accept a comment as an answer.